# Dont understand value of a and b after executing this code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't predict the values of a and b after executing this piece of code (or similar ones). How should I approach such a problem? I only know how simple for and if statements work.

```
a = 0
b = 2
for i in range(0,3):
       if i * 2 == a:
              a = b * 2
       else:
              b = a * b
```

Comment: It's not so simple to tell what the values of some variables will be just by staring at the code. Write down the execution steps of this code on a piece op paper and see if there are any patterns.

Comment: Also, using a debugger to view the state of variables as you step line-by-line through the code is an invaluable step for any programmer. If you aren't familiar with doing that, it's probably one of the most useful things you can learn to do as a beginner programmer, so I'd definitely recommend looking for an IDE, such as PyCharm, that lets you use debugging features.

Comment: `print("i: ",i,"a: ",a," b: ",b)`  Add this below the last line of your code to see the current state of a and b for each iteration of i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a beginner I would recommend creating two blocks with names, 'a', 'b', and 'i' since these three variables are used in this problem.

After that fill the blocks with their initial values, a = 0, b = 2, and i = 0 since it starts with zero in range(0,3) which goes till two.

Now, as you mentioned that you know workings of for and if statements, then you can easily update each block as per step executed.

I'll give the first run. Here, i = 0, a = 0, and b = 2.

i*2 = 0 * 2 = 0

Is i*2 == a? Yes, since 0 == 0, hence we go inside the if statement.

We update the value of 'a' as, a = b * 2 = 2 * 2 = 4

Thus, after the first iteration, i = 0, a = 4, and b = 2.